# Making JSON requests to fetch relationships asynchronously

Tags: javascript, react.js, promise, async-await

I would like to refactor the fetchRelationships function to use async await. I am not sure what the best way is to do it as this code contains nested `.then` at `response.json().then((json) =>....`

Could sby pls post the refactored version?

```
export const fetchRelationshipsError = (error) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_FAILURE,
    payload: { error }
  };
};

export const fetchRelationshipsRequest = () => {
  return { type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_REQUEST };
};

export const fetchRelationshipsSuccess = (relationships) => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_RELATIONSHIPS_SUCCESS,
    payload: relationships
  };
};

export const fetchRelationships = (url) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchRelationshipsRequest());

    fetch(url, config)
    .then((response) => {
      const responseObj = {
        response: response,
        payload: response.json().then((json) => {
          return { body: json }
        })
      };

      if (!response.ok) {
        const error = new Error(response.statusText);
        responseObj.payload.then((response) => {
          show_error_alert(response.body);
          dispatch(fetchRelationshipsError(response.body));
        });
        throw error;
      }

      return responseObj.payload;
    })
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch(fetchRelationshipsSuccess(response.body))
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log('Request failed', error); });
  };
};
```

Comment: We can review this code, but please be aware that responses might not provide the specific rewrite that you requested.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would get that error check out of the way instead of in the middle of the operation. Just throw an error in the middle of the operation and let the `catch` handle the dispatch.

Also, `fetch` will always resolve. A common procedure is to use the very first `then` to evaluate the response and determine how the sequence proceeds. It's usually either resolving with the data or rejecting with the error. But in your case, since both success and error actions dispatch body, the only difference is the action creator. Instead of a resolution/rejection, we just resolve with the correct action based on `ok`.

```
export const fetchRelationships = url => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchRelationshipsRequest())

    fetch(url, config)
      .then(res =>
        // We cannot return res.json() and do its then as part of the
        // outer sequence since we need res. This needs to nest.
        res.json().then(body => 
          res.ok ? fetchRelationshipsSuccess(body) : fetchRelationshipsError(body)))
      .then(action => dispatch(action))
      .catch((error) => dispatch(genericErrorAction())
  }
}
```

Now for `async-await`. The returned anonymous function from `fetchRelationships` will have to be `async` in order for its body to be able to use `await`. All promise-returning functions will need to use `await`. And then turn everything into synchronous-looking code. Here's the same procedure as above, but in `async-await` form.

```
export const fetchRelationships = url => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchRelationshipsRequest())

    try {
      const res = await fetch(url, config)
      const body = await res.json()
      const action = res.ok ? fetchRelationshipsSuccess(body) : fetchRelationshipsError(body)
      dispatch(action)
    } catch(error){
      dispatch(genericErrorAction())
    }
  }
}
```